# biblatex numbering different on two computers

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm running my CV, which is compiled by calling

```
pdflatex main
biber main --output-safechars
pdflatex main
pdflatex main % shouldn't be necessary but added delay negligible
```

When I run this script on my Linux Mint laptop running biber 1.8, everything comes out as I want, but when I run it on my Mac laptop running biber 2.1 I get weird things happening with the numbering. For this MWE, instead of getting numbering coming out as [1] and [1] as it should, I get [1] and [0], which doesn't make sense. The problem scales up as more examples are added, though I haven't been able to identify any clear patterns as I add files to MyPapers.bib

MWE as follows (only works as two separate files):

MyPapers.bib

```
@unpublished{exampletwo,
author = {Last-name, Firstname and lname, En\'{e}as},
booktitle = {In Review},
title = {{Pick a Title}}
}
@inproceedings{exampleone,
author = {Jones, Jim and Example, Jos\'{e}},
booktitle = {Sustentabilidade H{\'{\i}}drica}},
year = {2014}
}
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,roman]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}  
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% character

\usepackage{csquotes}


%---------------------Bibliography and BiBLaTeX--------------------
% Use BibLaTeX
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}

\makeatletter

% Print labelnumber as actual number, plus item total, minus one
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{bbx@itemtotal}+1-#1\relax}

% Initialize category counters
\def\bbx@initcategory#1{\csnumgdef{bbx@count@#1}{0}}
\forlistloop{\bbx@initcategory}{\blx@categories}

% Increment category counters
\def\bbx@countcategory#1{%
  \ifentrytype{#1}
    {\csnumgdef{bbx@count@#1}{\csuse{bbx@count@#1}+1}%
     \addtocategory{#1}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
     \listbreak}
    {}}
\AtDataInput{\forlistloop{\bbx@countcategory}{\blx@categories}}

% Modify \bibbycategory to set item total
\patchcmd{\blx@bibcategory}
  {\blx@key@heading{#1}}
  {\blx@key@heading{#1}%
   \csnumdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}%
   \csnumgdef{bbx@itemtotal}{\csuse{bbx@count@#1}}}
  {}{}

\makeatother
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{unpublished}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{inproceedings}


\defbibheading{bibliography}{\section*{Publications and  Presentations}}
\defbibheading{unpublished}{\subsection*{Articles In Review}}
\defbibheading{inproceedings}{\subsection*{Conference Papers}}

\addbibresource{MyPapers.bib}

%------------------------ personal data -------------------------------------
\name{Firstname}{Name}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

% Publications
\nocite{*} % count all pubs as cited
\printbibheading
\bibbycategory

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you are using all this internal patching. Don't you get your output with something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,roman]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% character

\usepackage{csquotes}


%---------------------Bibliography and BiBLaTeX--------------------
% Use BibLaTeX
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    sorting=ynt,defernumbers]{biblatex}

\defbibheading{bibliography}{\section*{Publications and  Presentations}}
\defbibheading{unpublished}{\subsection*{Articles In Review}}
\defbibheading{inproceedings}{\subsection*{Conference Papers}}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

%------------------------ personal data -------------------------------------
\name{Firstname}{Name}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

% Publications
\nocite{*} % count all pubs as cited
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[heading=unpublished,resetnumbers,type=unpublished]
\printbibliography[heading=inproceedings,resetnumbers,type=inproceedings]
\end{document}
```

Comment: the internal patching came from an answer given on SE previously. This code works, but is there a way to reverse the numbering so that the numbers count down rather than up?